# Partial ordering of a matrix entries

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I need this for experimentation in some work, so it is not without purpose.

Consider the in-spiraling and out-spiraling $4\times 4$ matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4 \\ 12&13&14&5 \\ 11&16&15&6 \\ 10&9&8&7
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\begin{pmatrix} 16&15&14&13 \\ 5&4&3&12 \\ 6&1&2&11 \\ 7&8&9&10
\end{pmatrix}.$$
For odd-dimensions, look at the $5\times 5$ matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5 \\ 16&17&18&19&6 \\ 15&24&25&20&7 \\ 14&23&22&21&8 \\ 13&12&11&10&9
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\begin{pmatrix} 17&16&15&14&13 \\ 18&5&4&3&12 \\ 19&6&1&2&11 \\ 20&7&8&9&10 \\ 21&22&23&24&25
\end{pmatrix}.$$

> **Question.** What is a *Maple* code for generating such $n\times n$ matrices?

**Remark.** Although I wish for a Maple code, it might also be useful for other readers if you write alternative venues such as *Mathematica* or *Sage*, etc.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/